# Refactor on multi project in Visual Studio with lots of "Linked Files"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, refactoring

I have several C# project in different solution of Visual Studio.
There are many .cs file that are referenced from different project (NOT copy of same .cs file, but only 1 file and several reference in several project).

Now I have created a general solution (.sln) where are imported ALL my project (.csproject)

What I need is refactor some variable name in ALL my project.

I try to open in visual studio the .cs file and do a refactor but it change all name of that variable only inside THAT project and NOT of all project! And if I mouve inside other project i found the error because that variable is not find and I can't do refactor in the same way...

So, what I can do?

I give some other info:

- All project compile separatly in each separate solution.
- In general solution I import all *.csproj and if i build all project simultaneously or separately they correctly build.
- all .cs files that are referenced in many project were added by link and NOT copied
- If I open one common .cs file in one project (.csproj) and try to open the same .cs inside another project (.csproj) visual studio give me the error "the file is already opened in another project of solution"
- maybe the most important thing: If I open one common .cs file in one project I can navigate inside his functions... In visual studio upper the function there is a small menu that tell ALL reference of that function inside the project.
  OK, in this menu I see only the reference inside the project where i open the file and NOT the reference of the other project of my solution.
  example: in file "utility.cs" I have function named "TryConvertMatrix(..)". I have one project named "river" that use this function and onother project named "telephone" that use this function. In both project the file "utility.cs" was added as link. If I open file "utility.cs" from project "river" I see all reference of the function  "TryConvertMatrix(..)" inside the .cs files of project "river" but NOT where was called inside .cs file of "telephone" project
- In the example explaned before, if I try to refactor the name of function "TryConvertMatrix(..)" in "ConvertPerfectMatrix(..)" Visual Studio, correctly, change all reference ONLY inside "river" project! 
  So when I navigate inside the project "telephone" I find all calling to "TryConvertMatrix(..)" instead the new name so it can't build! And, in this case, I can't do a refactor in this project because... No build ---> No refactor

What I need is only change a name of a variable and ALL reference in ALL project that I have opened in my solution.

I try do delete all project's bin folder, restart visual studio and rebulild
In this way no improvement...

Many thanks,
Massimiliano

Comment: Does your holdall solution rebuild ok if you delete all bin folders?

Comment: Hi Ian Ringrose. Yes, If I delete all the bin folder , still compile correctly....

Comment: So you do a complete rebuild and it ALL builds OK, then do one refactoring, and it no longer builds for a complete rebuild...   You need another developer to sit down with you at your computer, something "odd" is going on - once it starts working I expect you will never be able to repeat the problem.

Comment: I assume that you exited and restart visual-studio before AND after the complete rebuild, before doing the refactoring.   99% of the time it is that visual-studio has not updated one of its temperoy files, or has failed to correctly load a file that has change on disk.

Comment: Hi Ian, I answer editing main topic. I can tell you that I restert visual studio, I try to refactor one function name in one project and the OTHER project will not compile (because were changed one name of a funciont that this porject use)
An important info: All common .cs file are added as a link

Comment: I think you need to resign you system so you don't have  "common .cs file that are added as a link."  e.g. put your common code in a dll that is used by the rest of your projects.    "linked files" have always given me pain!